# Counter Example of $\cup$ A$_i$ is not compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples

True or false: The union of an arbitrary family of compact subsets is a compact subset.

Well firstly I think for a while if it is true or not, definitely I take the second option and in order to prove that it false I think for the next counter example:

I take $\mathbb{R}$ as the working space with the discrete topology, so I think about the subset of only one element that all of them are compact so as $\mathbb{R}$ is non numerable we can't affirm that the union of all of this subset is compact because is a non numerable union so if we try to obtain a finite union that contains all of the elements it will be impossible.

I'm not sure if it is right or not.

Comment: Not at all, my question is if my answer to the problem is right or not and also if the way I write it is correct.

Comment: All finite sets are compact and every set $S$ is a union of a family of finite sets, e.g. $S=\cup_{x\in S}\,\{x\},$ but not every set is compact.

Comment: You are right but the style could be better.

Comment: @Alvaro.  Your writing is good .  However "non" is not a word, it is a prefix. Thus "not numerable" or "non-numerable." "union of all of this subset" should be "union of all these subsets" and "because is a" needs to include a subject, "because it is."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\Bbb R$ in the discrete metric/topology, a subset $A$ is compact iff $A$ is finite. So e.g. take $A_n = \{n\}$, all compact, and then $\Bbb N = \bigcup_n A_n$ is not compact. So it already fails with countable unions of finite sets.